# Is it allowed to call CreateRemoteThread() on a suspended process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

If I suspend a process using (undocumented) `NtSuspendProcess` function (exported from `ntdll.dll`) and then call [`CreateRemoteThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) to create a thread in that process, the thread starts running without any issues.

I'm wondering if that is an allowed use for `CreateRemoteThread`?

Comment: Since you are already using (undocumented) `NtSuspendProcess` why do you bother to care whether it is allowed to use `CreateRemoteThread` like this?

Comment: Well, why wouldn't it start running. You create a thread in a remote process, and ask it to start running. It starts running and you wonder why? What would you expect to happen?

Comment: `NtSuspendProcess` enumerate and suspends all none-exiting threads in the target process. nothing prevent new create thread from run. so new thread created by `CreateRemoteThread` start execute in user mode. but .. you suspend all existing threads in arbitrary place. possible some suspended thread hold process global critical section. and when new thread try enter to this section - he hung here. this can be and loader lock. or say process heap crit sec if you suspend thread while it allocate or free memory). so will be nw thread run ok or hung - rundom

Comment: @VTT & David: so many questions, so little info.

Comment: @RbMm: yeah, good point. I didn't realize it until I looked into `NtSuspendProcess` that [all it does](https://ntopcode.wordpress.com/tag/ntsuspendprocess/) is it enums process threads and suspends them from within a lock. In other words, there's no such thing as "suspended process". It's just threads that can suspended. Altho I see ur point about a potential deadlock in that remote thread if it happens to call, idk, LoadLibrary while another call to the same API was suspended in another thread. Although, I don't see how that would be different from calling documented SuspendThread instead.

Comment: exist [src code](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ps/psspnd.c) for this. this call have the same effect as you enumerate all threads in process and suspend every thread yourself. problem in point, where you suspend thread. if thread hold some lock - your new thread can begin wait for this lock, until you not resume process

Comment: @c00000fd That's what happens when the question is so vague. I've still no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @RbMm: yes, I understand. That's why it's dangerous to suspend any thread. (The code you listed though is the kernel code. It's not a problem to do it there. The function I was referring to, CreateRemoteThread, is the user-mode function.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm seriously wondering, do you really have nothing else to do other than engage into this polemic?

Comment: The question still is completely unclear. Your talk of user and kernel mode misses the point. NtSuspendProcess is also a user mode function. Obviously it makes sys calls to suspend the threads. Just as CreateRemoteThread makes sys calls to create the thread. The danger RbMm refers to does not arise from making user mode calls. It arises from deadlocking on objects held by suspended threads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The reason I asked this question was my original understanding of the "suspend process" term. Now I see that there's no such thing as a "suspended process". Suspension in Windows only applies to threads. My original assumption was that the process had an internal flag that could signify it as being suspended, and thus any thread in it would be suspended from the get go. Thus my asking the question. Now, I see that this is not the case. As for the kernel reference, Rbmm gave that code sample above that used kernel function calls and that is why I brought this up for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, I have done it. The new thread will start executing immediately, unless the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag is set on `CreateRemoteThread();`.

And yes, that how it should work, to answer your question.