Error: Module Not Found When Injecting DLL
I'm trying to learn how to inject a DLL into a process. To do so, I've set up a new project with:

HelloWorld.exe which displays a message box.
hook_msg.dll which implements the hook using (correctly?) minhook
injector.exe which is supposed to inject hook_msg.dll into HelloWorld.exe.

When I run injector.exe, I only get the HelloWorld message box and nothing from the injected DLL (I expect another message box).
To give you more context, walking through the process with x64dbg showed that the last error was ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND.
Below is more information on my approach trying to solve the problem.
And here is the code and my configuration to compile it:
Injector:
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdio.h>

STARTUPINFO             startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION     processInformation;


BOOL InjectDLL(HANDLE hProcess, LPCTSTR dllPath)
{
    // I read on some other stack question that size matter so i used +1 for the null terminator
    SIZE_T dllPathSize = (_tcslen(dllPath) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
 
    // Allocating memory in the remote process
    LPVOID pRemoteDllPath = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, dllPathSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (pRemoteDllPath == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        //Put some info so i can see the memory address and confirm in x64dbg
        _tprintf(TEXT("Memory allocated at: %p\n"), pRemoteDllPath);
    }

    //Writing the DLL path to the remote process
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, (LPVOID)dllPath, dllPathSize, NULL))
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
         //Put some info so i can see the memory address and confirm in x64dbg
        _tprintf(TEXT("DLL path written to memory at: %p\n"), pRemoteDllPath);
    }

    // Reading the memory back to verify
    TCHAR* localBuffer = (TCHAR*)malloc(dllPathSize);
    if (localBuffer == NULL)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, localBuffer, dllPathSize, NULL))
    {
        free(localBuffer);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        //Here i wanted to check if the memory was read correctly
        _tprintf(TEXT("DLL path read from memory: %s\n"), localBuffer);
    }

    // Even displaying the raw bytes
    for (SIZE_T i = 0; i < dllPathSize; i++)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("%02X "), ((BYTE*)localBuffer)[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) _tprintf(TEXT("\n"));
    }
    _tprintf(TEXT("\n"));

    free(localBuffer);

    //Getting the address of LoadLibraryW in kernel32.dll
    LPVOID pLoadLibraryW = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "LoadLibraryW");
    if (pLoadLibraryW == NULL)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Creating a remote thread to load the DLL
    HANDLE hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)pLoadLibraryW, pRemoteDllPath, 0, NULL);
    if (hRemoteThread == NULL)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        // Print the handle of the remote thread
        _tprintf(TEXT("Handle du thread: %p\n"), hRemoteThread);

        // Get the ID of the remote thread
        DWORD threadId = GetThreadId(hRemoteThread);
        _tprintf(TEXT("ID du thread: %lu\n"), threadId);
    }
    // Wait for the remote thread to complete
    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);

    // Free the allocated memory and close the thread handle
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);

    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    TCHAR targetPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR hookdllpath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR modulePath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR *lastSlash;

    // Get the path of the current executable
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, modulePath, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Find the last backslash in the path
    lastSlash = _tcsrchr(modulePath, '\\');
    if (lastSlash == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Replace the executable name with "helloworld.exe"
    _tcscpy(lastSlash + 1, TEXT("helloworld.exe"));

    // Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    // Initialize the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    // Starting a new process
    if (!CreateProcess(modulePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Get the path of the DLL to inject
    if (GetFullPathName(TEXT("hooking_msg.dll"), MAX_PATH, targetPath, NULL) == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


    // Inject the DLL into the process
    if (!InjectDLL(processInformation.hProcess, targetPath))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


    // Resume the suspended process
    ResumeThread(processInformation.hThread);

    // Wait for the process to complete
    WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles
    CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);

    return TRUE;
}

Compiled with:
{
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build injector",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe:",
                "${workspaceFolder}/injector.exe", 
                "${workspaceFolder}/injector.cpp", 
                "user32.lib",
                "/link",
                "/MACHINE:X86"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }

hook_msg.dll :
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MinHook.h"

typedef int (WINAPI *MESSAGEBOXW)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);

// Pointer for calling original MessageBoxW.
MESSAGEBOXW fpMessageBoxW = NULL;

// Detour function which overrides MessageBoxW.
int WINAPI DetourMessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    return fpMessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Hooked!", lpCaption, uType);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{



    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        // Initialize MinHook.
        if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Get the address of MessageBoxW from user32.dll.
        HMODULE hUser32 = GetModuleHandleW(L"user32.dll");
        if (hUser32 == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        FARPROC pMessageBoxW = GetProcAddress(hUser32, "MessageBoxW");
        if (pMessageBoxW == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Create a hook for MessageBoxW, in disabled state.
        if (MH_CreateHook(pMessageBoxW, &DetourMessageBoxW, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&fpMessageBoxW)) != MH_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Enable the hook for MessageBoxW.
        if (MH_EnableHook(pMessageBoxW) != MH_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        break;
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        // Disable the hook for MessageBoxW.
        if (MH_DisableHook(&MessageBoxW) != MH_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Uninitialize MinHook.
        if (MH_Uninitialize() != MH_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        break;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

compiled with:
{
            "label": "build DLL",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/LD", 
                "/EHsc",
                "/MTd",
                "/Fe:",
                "${workspaceFolder}/hooking_msg.dll", 
                "${workspaceFolder}/hooking_msg.cpp", 
                "user32.lib",
                "/I", "G:\\01_Doc\\05_Projects\\MinHook_133_lib\\include",
                "/link",
                "/MACHINE:X86",
                "/LIBPATH:G:\\01_Doc\\05_Projects\\MinHook_133_lib\\lib",
                "G:\\01_Doc\\05_Projects\\MinHook_133_lib\\lib\\libMinHook-x86-v141-mtd.lib"

                
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"]
        }

Hello world:
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"HelloWorld", L"Message", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

compiled with:
{
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe:",
                "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe", 
                "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.cpp",
                "user32.lib",
                "/link",
                "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS",
                "/MACHINE:X86"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }

I first read this post on stack CreateRemoteThread() succeeds yet doesn't do anything
As it wasn't solving my issue I tryed to log some info to be sure that the path is well written in the target process, the log are ok:
injector logs
I also used a dependency walker to see if there was unsolved dependency but it seems to be ok.
Then i used x64dbg to walk throught the code of both injector and target process, first i run injector from x64dbg, I break just before the creation of the target thread. Then i attach an other instance of x64dbg to helloworld.exe to watch the call of LoadLibraryW.
The dll path is correctly given to the target process with full path, yet the function LoadLibraryW end with LastError ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND and LastStatus STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.
Maybe my hook implementation is not good? Or something else... I don't know what to check now to troubleshot.
Thank you for your help.

You are injecting the DLL into a new process that is created with CREATE_SUSPENDED. The process's main thread is not running yet, and so other DLLs that the process uses are not loaded until the main thread begins running. That includes kernel32.dll, which your hook is trying to use.
If you want your hook to run when the new process begins running, you will have to use a different technique to load the DLL, such as queuing an APC request to the process's main thread, or even patching the process's entry point (MS Detours can handle that for you), etc.

Thanks, yet I am a little confuse because my code is directly inspired from this repo hooks_exemple and this article Windows API Hooking and DLL Injection which use the same technique so is this not working at all or am i missing something?
If I run my injector in debug and break before CreateRemoteThread then attach xdbg64 to helloworld.exe then create the new thread, I can see that the thread crated is running, is their something I dont get?

When a new process is created suspended, its main thread is frozen, and so there is nothing running to load DLLs or create secondary threads. But you are creating a new thread remotely, so it can start running even though the main thread is still frozen (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517595/). But you won't be able to use functions in kernel32 since it hasn't been loaded yet.

Ok thank you for the precision, found also this about this issue : dll-injection-not-working-in-suspended-process. And this artical to by pass the issue opcode0x90.wordpress. But as you suggested, i ll try APC as it seems to be a more appropriate technique.
